# What is unwrap equivalent in OpenSSL.Connection?

Tags: python, sockets, openssl, pyopenssl

I'm using OpenSSL, I want to close the SSL connection but want to keep the underlying plain socket connection alive. The SSL library seems to have [an `unwrap` function for it](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLSocket.unwrap). What would be the equivalent way to achieve it using the `OpenSSL.Connection` class?

Also is it even possible to downgrade an SSL connection from server?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
import socket
from OpenSSL import Connection
sslsock = socket.socket()
# Setup your socket here...
sslcon = OpenSSL(context, sslsock)
# Use your socket...
sslcon.shutdown()
# You should be able to use sslsocket
# until you...
sslsock.close()
```

I haven't tried so let me know if it works.